# Add a Json Value dynamically in POSTGRESQL

Tags: json, postgresql

In postgresql, I've a table with a column named source of type json.

The source contains Json as below. I need to select the source column but the output should produce the result as below

**Input**

```
{
    "filters": {
        "operator": "EQ",
        "value": "name",
        "type": "string"
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
   {
        "filters": {
            "operator": "EQ",
            "value": "name",
            "type": "string",   
            "args": ["cat"]
        }
    }
```

I was able to achieve this programatically using javascript, but please help me if it can be done via postgresql select statement itself.

Comment: What should happen if the input already contains an `args` property?

Comment: If args contain, it should replace it. In my case, it won't be present

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [jsonb_set](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-PROCESSING-TABLE) function.

```sql
select jsonb_set(
'{
    "filters": {
        "operator": "EQ",
        "value": "name",
        "type": "string"
    }
}'::jsonb,        -- the input value
'{filters,args}', -- new element path 
'["cat"]'         -- new element value
);
```

Result:

```json
{
  "filters": {
    "args": ["cat"],
    "type": "string",
    "value": "name",
    "operator": "EQ"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `jsonb_set` or `jsonb_insert` functions can be used for this. For example:

```
SELECT jsonb_set(myvalue, '{filters,args}', '["cat"]') FROM mytable;
```

will select the `myvalue` column from `mytable`, except adding the "args" value as in your example.

The [JSON Functions and Operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html) and [JSON Types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-json.html) sections of the documentation have more detailed information.